# Split cookies from page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I was doing some coding today, but I got an error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') 
    at getCookie ((index):38:49)
    at (index):47:31
```

My code (begins at line 36, ends at 43):

```
var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
    var cookiePair = cookieArray[1].split("=");
    
    if(name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
        return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1])
    }
}
```

Btw, I've read that you can only split a string, but this is a string right?

Comment: "but this is a string right" — No. The error message clearly says it is `undefined`

Comment: The code *expects* it to be a string, but the error indicates that there is no string there.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: You have `1` in multiple places where you wanted to put `i` instead

Comment: `cookieArray[1]` is `undefined` because your array has only one item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `i` instead of `1`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
   var cookiePair = cookieArray[i].split("=");

   if(name== cookiePair[0].trim()) {
      return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[i])
   }
}
```

Because the first time it iterates the array `cookieArray[1]` my be undefind.